# How would I switch an animation track between continuous and discrete mid-animation?

Tags: animation, godot, godot-3

How could I set it so that an animation track switches update mode mid animation? For example, when I need to have separate parts of a sprite's image remain in place as the frame changes?

### An example of what I would like to know how to do:

Create an animation like this:

[image: A diagram of an animation track changing from continuous to discrete]

*(*off)*

so that a node's movement might look something along the lines of like this *(suppose we actually wanted it to jump across the screen)*:

[image: An animation of the Godot icon moving left and right; jumping mid animation]